# Are default values for a column still required if using audit triggers?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, default-value, postgresql-15

I have a couple of audit columns in my table:

- modified_by
- modified_date

I have an AFTER trigger set up to automatically update these columns whenever data is inserted or modified, with current_user and current_timestamp respectively.

Would there be any benefit in also adding these as default column values (I assume not given that inserts are already handled by the trigger)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work (well) with an `AFTER` trigger. You need a `BEFORE` trigger that modifies the rows *before* it is added. Then you don't need to worry about `DEFAULT` values, because constraints and nullability are checked after a `BEFORE` trigger runs. Moreover, modifying the row after you inserted it is much more costly than adjusting the row before it is inserted.